# How to make Laravel/Vue implementation show individual entry

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to integrate Laravel with Vue, and further down the line Nuxt, in the hope that I can integrate snazzy page transitions like the ones shown on http://page-transitions.com into my websites.

I've been reading a tutorial about using Vue with Laravel; https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-guestbook-with-laravel-and-vuejs, and I was pleased to find that Laravel ships with a Vue implementation, so I thought there'd be quite a lot of info on how to use the two in combination, but there doesn't seem to be.

I completed the tutorial and made the guestbook as it was described. I'm now trying to build upon that.

Specifically, Im trying to create individual pages for each of the guestbook entries.

I do have quite a bit of experience using Laravel, but only what I've described above with Vue.

So, in order to create the individual pages, I've created a new route in the `routes/web.php` file;

`Route::get('signature/{id}','SignaturesController@show')->name('signature');`

I've then created a new code block in `app/Http/Controllers/SignaturesController.php` to deal with this request;

`public function show()
{
    return view('signatures.signature');
}`

I've created the specified view in `resources/views/signatures/signature.php`;

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <signature></signature>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection`
```

And I've created the vue file that should integrate with this view in `resources/assets/js/components/Signature.vue`;

```
<template>
    <h1>Signature</h1>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

    }
</script>
```

Finally, I've registered the component in `resources/assets/js/app.js` and reran `npm run dev`.

This has worked to an extenet, I can view the file at the expected url; `http://transitions.localhost/signature/1`.

My question is, how do I get the data related to the signature with the ID of 1 into the page? I can't even echo out `{{ id }}` or `{{ signature }}`.

Any other resources that you've found helpful regarding this subject would also be greatly appreciated. Thanks for taking the time to read through all of that, does anyone know where I go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to pass the data to your vue component

Maybe something like this?

In your view:

```
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <signature :signature="{{ $signature }}"></signature>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

In your vue component:

```
<template>
    <h1>This signature has the ID of: {{ signature.id }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['signature']
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, I needed to make a couple of other changes elsewhere too but this set me on the right path. Thanks once again for the rapid and helpful reply.